# arcpy: I would like to join a .xls table to a .shp table using two common fields

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins

arcpy: I would like to join a .xls table to a .shp table using two common fields, instead of one common field.

Is this possible in ArcGIS using python?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but you could easily create a new field in each table and populate it with a concatenation of the two fields you are interested in... would that accomplish what you need?

Comment: The only way to join on two fields is using the Make Query Table tool.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006r000000  However, that tool generally does not work well with tables that do not support ObjectIDs, like xls tables.  You may have to convert the xls table into a dbf or geodatabase table to make it work.  The concatenation suggestion mr. adam gave may work the best if you want to stay with an .xls file.

Comment: These are both great ideas. I will try both

Comment: mr.adam Your concatenation solution worked, and will be an easy addition to my enterprise join script. Thank you!   Richard Fairhurst, I am now going to try and work your solution.

Comment: ok, for good measure I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible, but you could easily create a new field in each table, populate it with a concatenation of the two fields you are interested in, and then use that new field for the join.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to create a concatenated field in both the spreadsheet and the feature class, then use the [Excel to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) function to get your spreadsheet into a table, then use [Add Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000) function to finish the join. Python would go a little something like this:

```
import arcpy
env.workspace = "path to workspace"

excel_file = r"path to file"
input_fc = r"path to shapefile"
output_table = r"path to output table"

converted_table = arcpy.ExcelToTable_coversion(excel_file, output_table, "Sheet1")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_fc, "temp_layer")
acrpy.AddJoin_management("temp_layer", "IN_FIELD", converted_table, "JOIN_FIELD", "KEEP_COMMON")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("temp_layer, "path and name for output")
```